# visual + aural in one word

Tags: single-word-requests

I want an adjective that means, visuals + its accompanying audio. A word to describe the experience that video is.

> Video is a(n) ______ experience

or

> A(n) _______ story

Comment: Are you looking for the word [**audiovisual**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/audiovisual)?

Comment: @WeatherVane yess

Comment: @WeatherVane do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the word **audiovisual**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/audiovisual) has

> **audiovisual**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Using both sight and sound, typically in the form of images and recorded speech or music.
> *learners can be encouraged to use audiovisual aids*

The first sentence doesn't work very well just copying this into the blank, so that would need to be rephrased.

The second sentence could be expanded into something like:

> Today in school we shared an audiovisual story.